# How to make the bullets of an unordered list have different text-decoration than the list items

Tags: html, css

**What I need:** The list items to be underlined and be a different color from the bullet points, which should not be underlined

**What I've tried:**

A scenario of my issue is http://jsfiddle.net/g7fgy70c/

*HTML* (Can't change this structure because I'm working through a CMS)

```
<ul>
    <li><a hfref="http://www.google.com">This should be underlined, but the bullet before it should not be</a></li>
     <li><a hfref="http://www.google.com">This should be underlined, but the bullet before it should not be</a></li>   
     <li><a hfref="http://www.google.com">This should be underlined, but the bullet before it should not be</a></li>
</ul>
```

*CSS*

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

a
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

li > a:before
{
    content: "\002022";
    color: red;
    padding-right: 5px;
    /* text-decoration: none; DOES NOT WORK, THE BULLETS ARE STILL UNDERLINED */
}
```

Comment: Put the pseudo element on the list item instead? - http://jsfiddle.net/g7fgy70c/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Target li not li >a : http://jsfiddle.net/g7fgy70c/3/

```
li:before
{
    content: "\002022";
    color: red;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```